# Dynamic LINQ with a string?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an entity object from an existing table that is a `Question` table.

**Question**:

```
Id
Value
```

I have another entity object that is an `Answer` table, however, it is very flat:

**QuestionAnswer**:

```
Identity COL | QuestionAnswer1 | QuestionAnswer2 | QuestionAnswer3 ...
```

I'm trying to build an HTML table where I display the questions in 1 column but then the answers in the column next to it.

But since the Answer table is flat I'm having issues with it.

```
@{int iCount = 0;
  string answerKey = "";}
@foreach (var item in Model.Questions) {
var calc = iCount + 1;
answerKey = "QuestionAnswer" + calc.ToString();

<tr>
    <td>@Model.Questions[iCount].Question</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>@Model.Answers[0].QuestionAnswer1</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
 iCount++;
}
```

I can display the Questions perfectly but because of the way the table is set up QuestionAnswer1 displays for all questions that are display which isn't correct:

```
Question1 | QA1
Question2 | QA1
Question3 | QA1
...
```

**I want it to be**

```
Question1 | QA1
Question2 | QA2
Question3 | QA3
...
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to build the column name using the iCount variable:

```
string QA = "QuestionAnswer"+iCount;
```

**Then I could do something like this:**

```
<td>@Model.Answers[0].QA</td>
```

But that isn't right...  Can I do something like this or is there another way that is very obvious?

**Here is the Model that I'm using:**

```
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionAnswer> QuestionAnswers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you paste the C# class definitions for your models?

Comment: I'm using entity framework so my objects are from the DB itself (Question and QuestionAnswer) which I posted in my question.  I'll post the model but it is just 2 lists (Question and QuestionAnswer).

Comment: I'm really unclear what this has to do with linq or dynamic linq...

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - What I'd like to do is to build a linq query with the column name (that is built at run time i.e. "QuestionAnswer1", "QuestionAnswer2", "QuestionAnswer3") is that possible

Comment: What is `iCount`? Where does that come in?

Comment: Also, does `QuestionAnswer` have a reference (hard or soft) to `Question`? You have to be able to match them up somehow. If you can then this should be possible.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - I updated my question.  Hopefully it is more clear on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I understand now what you're asking, but that is the wrong approach for a statically typed language. It *is* possible using reflection but is neither easy nor preformant. If you *really* want to do something like this than use Dictionaries instead of hardcoded models. However, an even better approach would be to correlate the question with the correct answer in your viewmodel, before it ever gets sent to the view.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - I'm pretty sure you are right.  I was hoping there was something easy in Linq or Razor to handle this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely right :P

Comment: It seems to me you are misinterpreting the table structure. QuestionAnswer1, QuestionAnswer2, QuestionAnswer3 seem to be multiple different answers for the same question, as opposed to answers for seperate questions. Also, answers should be correlated to questions by some means. For example, if they are correlated by ordinal position (row number) then @Model.Answers[0].QuestionAnswer1 should be changed to @Model.Answers[iCount].QuestionAnswer1.

Comment: I agree with George.  It seems like there should be a model in your controller that builds a data structure with a list of questions, each question with a list of answers.  You'll get better separation of concerns that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with George that this has very little to do with Linq, and I would expect one or more layers between your DB and view.

- Bind to a ViewModel
- Create an object that contains both the question and corresponding answer
- Populate a list of said objects in your ViewModel from the Questions/Answers with the appropriate data
- Bind to the list, and for each row simply bind to Question and Answer

You're talking business logic about how the questions and answers actually link up to each other, and it seems unnecessary to try to tackle this in your view if it isn't a straightforward relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with my code.

```
<table class="table" style="table-layout:auto;width:20%;">
    <tr>
    <td>Question | Answer</td>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.Questions[i].Question @Model.Questions[i].QuestionID  
        </td>           
        <td>
            |
        </td>
        <td >
            @Model.Answers[i].Answer
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```